# Generating Function for the following sequences

Tags: generating-functions

Find the Generating Function for the following sequences

$a)1,4,16,64,256$

$b)2,4,8,16,32\cdots $

My Attempt-:
$a)G\left ( x \right )=\sum_{n=0}^{n=4}4^{k}x^{k}=\sum_{n=0}^{n=4}\left ( 4x \right )^{k}=\frac{\left ( 4x \right )^{5}-1}{4x-1}$

$b)G\left ( x \right )=\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty}2^{n}x^{n}=\frac{1}{1-2}$

Is My Attempt right ?

Comment: how do you define the term _generating function for a sequence_?

Comment: why ???you mean that we cannot define generating function for a sequence..???? question is from Kenneth H Rosen

Comment: I'm not saying by any means that we cannot define them. I only wanted to know the definition.

Comment: $Generating$ $Function $  $ G\left ( x \right )=\sum_{k=0}^{k=\infty}a_{k}x^{k}$